# C++ Ncurses is duplicating output

Tags: c++, ncurses

I just started working with ncurses in c++, and I tried to write a basic hello world program. However, when I run the code, I get

> Hello World!Hello World!

instead of just "Hello World!" nine times out of ten. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Here is my code:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    raw();
    printw("Hello World!");
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. I suspect your `TERM` environment variable isn't set correctly.

Comment: How would I check to see what might be wrong with that, and how would I fix it?

Comment: Do you have problems with any other full-screen applications?

Comment: No, none at all. Vim, nano, and lynx all work just fine. I just checked my environment variables, and `TERM` was set to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: You see the double output before you press a character to exit the program?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't happen every time, it will occasionally print the correct output, but this is rare.

Comment: This is really the whole program? It looks fine and I wasn't able to reproduce. I tried about 10 times.

Comment: Yep. I am compiling it with `g++ fileName.cpp -o out -lncurses`. I couldn't find anything similar on google.

Comment: I added `getch()` immediately before the `printw`, and that stopped it, but I can't get it to work without that.